# New question 'Next' button issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When entering the title of a new question, the iOS keyboard gets a 'Next' button:

[image: next button]

Tapping it doesn't appear to do anything.

(using 1.0.1.86)

Comment: Reproduced in 1.0.1.87 as well, think it should focus the next element, i.e. the Body textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated this behavior to work as expected: Tapping next will focus on the body text view.

This change should be apparent in **beta version 1.0.1.88.**